# Unmarshalling maxOccurs unbounded elements having attributes through jaxb

Tags: java, jaxb

I am trying to unmarshal xml response(parsing with JAXB) conforming to following xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xsd:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="response" type="responseType" />
  <xsd:complexType name="responseType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="result" type="resultType" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="resultType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="doc" type="docType" />
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="start" type="xsd:int" />
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="docType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element minOccurs="1" name="int" type="intType" maxOccurs="unbounded"  />
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1" name="str" type="strType" />
      <xsd:element name="float" type="floatType" />
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1" name="long" type="longType" />
      <xsd:element name="date" type="dateType" />    
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="dateType">
            <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="longType">
    <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="floatType">
    <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="strType">
    <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="intType">
    <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

I've also generated the classes successfully using xjc tool.
But, I am unable to get the text of all maxoccurs unbounded elements : int,str,long nodes.
Since, these elements are unbounded, I get a list of each of these element of type ArrayList through methods in generated classes. And, a method to get value of the attribute. 
But generated classes don't provide a method to get value of the text node.

For eg: if my response is:

```
<response>
<result start="0">
<doc>
  <int name="age">0</int> 
  <str name="continent">EU</str> 
  <str name="country">United Kingdom</str> 
  <float name="influence">7.0</float> 
  <int name="classified">0</int> 
  <date name="createdOnGMTDate">2011-10-12T08:11:07Z</date> 
  <int name="favCnt">41</int> 
  <long name="id">120493600</long> 
  <long name="inReplyToId">-1</long> 
  <str name="isBookmarked">False</str> 
  <str name="lang">english</str> 
  <str name="language">english.lm</str> 
  <int name="listedCnt">6</int> 
  <str name="name">john doe</str> 
  <str name="screenName">john_d</str> 
  <int name="sentiment">-1</int>
  <str name="timeZone">London</str> 
  <str name="Text">Yeah gee got flashed in the W.C.....</str> 
  <str name="usrCrtDate">2011-10-12 08:11:07</str> 
  </doc>
<result>
<response>
```

then, I able to retrieve attribute names like continent, country but not its node values EU, United Kingdom respectively.

I think there's some issue in my xsd or in generated classes. Kindly assist.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your XML schema should look something like the following to capture both an attribute and text value:

```
  <xsd:complexType name="floatType">
    <xsd:simpleContent>
        <xsd:extension base="xsd:float">
            <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
        </xsd:extension
    </xsd:simpleContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

The text node will be mapped in JAXB with `@XmlValue`.  For more information see:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/jaxb-and-complex-types-with-simple.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your xml conforms to the schema you provided.

```
  <xsd:complexType name="strType">
    <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
  </xsd:complexType>
```

That doesn't make any mention of a child element. I think you need to extend the xsd base types (xsd:string etc.) and add an attribute.